# How to execute top 10 JPA repository

Tags: java, jpa

How to write this query on JPA repository?

```
select TOP(10) id_libro, count(*) as occ from noleggi 
group by id_libro
order by occ desc
```

My entity:

```
public class Noleggio {

@Id
@NotNull
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;


@NotNull
@Column(name = "inizio_prestito")
private LocalDate inizioPrestito;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "fine_prestito")
private LocalDate finePrestito;

@NotNull
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_utente")
private Utente utente;

@NotNull
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_libro")
private Libro libro;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use nativeQuery property of @Query annotation applying it to JPA repository method that sometimes a quite useful for aggregate or complex queries, for example:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface NoleggioRepository extends CrudRepository<Noleggio, Long> {

    @Query(value = "select TOP(10) id_libro from noleggio order by occ desc", nativeQuery=true)
List<Noleggio> findSomethingFromNoleggio();

}
```

More info: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#NativeQueries

Comment: I tried that                                                                                                
 @Query(value = "SELECT TOP(10) id_libro, COUNT(*) as occ from noleggi  GROUP BY id_libro ORDER BY occ desc ",
nativeQuery=true)                                                                                                                               
 List<Noleggio> findTop10ByLibroId();

Comment: Did you try to run this query directly in database? Do you receive the error?

Comment: query on database returns this:     id_libro | occ --->                                                                                                                                                                                                                - 32 |   7
- 45 | 3
- 20010   | 3
- 26 | 2
- 47 | 2
- 50 | 2
- 49 | 1
- 43 | 1
- 42 | 1
- 33 | 1